# Pyodbc- If table exist then don't create in SSMS

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying something like:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver ='{SQL Server}' ,server ='host-MOBL\instance',database ='dbname', trusted_connection = 'yes' )
cursor = cnxn.cursor()


cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName'""")

def checkTableExists(cnxn, TableName):
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{0}'
    """.format(TableName.replace('\'', '\'\'')))
    if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 1:
        cursor.close()
        return True

    cursor.close()
    return False

if checkTableExists == True:
    print ("already")
elif checkTableExists == False:
    print ("No")
```

But there is nothing happen, can anyone help me on this?
I am using Micrsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Express version.
The code will be run in Python.
Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the built-in [Cursor.tables](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#tablestablenone-catalognone-schemanone-tabletypenone) method for this check - following code sample assumes connection and cursor are instantiated

```
if cursor.tables(table='TableName', tableType='TABLE').fetchone():
    print("exists")
else:
    print("doesn't exist")
```

Note this isn't functionally different from querying [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx), but allows code portability with different database platforms (and IMO improves readability).

Using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 and SQL Server 2014, calling `Cursor.tables` just executes the [sp_tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186250.aspx) system stored procedure.

Comment: Wow, this is great, can use on different database platforms is a better way to solve problem !

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=yourserver.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=your_db;UID=your_username;PWD=your_password;TDS_Version=7.2;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'your_table_name')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Your table exists.' AS result
    END
""")

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row.result)
```

That prints "Table Exists" for me. You should be able to modify it to your needs.

Comment: ermm, I have try this before but it is not what I want, by the way I just don't know why it doesn't work for me, it suppose to be work like yours. Thx anyway, good answer

Comment: Bryan's suggestion is definitely better, I went SQL Server specific but his solution is much more robust.

Comment: @Bryan I have upvote yours and his answer, Thx  for you guys help